# How accessing to mom file in momd package?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I need your help,
I'm learning the coreData migration and I can't access to the two models file inside my momd package.

I've done this :

In the init method for the two models:

```
urlModel2 =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DeptB" withExtension:@"mom"];
```

And in an other method :

```
NSManagedObjectModel* model2 = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self urlModel2]];
```

I would like to have my two models in each NSManagedObjectModel to do a verification :

```
    NSMappingModel *mappingModel =
    [NSMappingModel inferredMappingModelForSourceModel:[self sourceModel]
                    destinationModel:[self destinationModel] error:outError];
```

you can found this at : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
NSString* pathMOMD = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Dept" ofType:@"momd"];
NSBundle* bundleMOMD = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:pathMOMD];

// model 1
NSString* pathMOM = [bundleMOMD pathForResource:@"DeptB" ofType:@"mom"];
urlModel1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathMOM];
NSManagedObjectModel* model1 = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self urlModel1]];
if(!model1){ NSLog(@"Problem for Model1"); }else{ NSLog(@"ok 1");}
```